# Segmentation Fault problem when running monerod in whonix

Tags: monerod, linux, tor

The first time I ran monerod in whonix, everything worked perfectly. But everytime after that, when I try to start it up, everything looks normal (green line read: NET service bound to ...)(second green line read: core rpc server initialized OK on port ...), but then (after 5 more white lines of stuff) I get Segmentation fault and everything stops.

What do I do to fix this?

Is the problem with monerod, whonix, or my OS?

My whonix freezes sometimes after awhile especially with multiple programs up.
Also, I notice my monero folder on my base OS has a monero-wallet-cli.log but on my whonix instance my monero folder never makes one of those that I see at least (it is the 32 bit version (v0-10-0-0) on whonix, but 64 bit version on my base OS)

Comment: It looks like based on [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132192/running-application-ends-with-segmentation-fault) it is a problem with monerod

Comment: What version of monerod are you running?

Answer (score 0):

`monerod` having a Segmentation Fault is likely an issue with `monerod` - However for anyone who comes here from Google, OP's version is v0.10, which is from 2016. **Updating your Monero version will likely fix the issue.**

If you have the latest Monero verison, create an issue on the [Monero Github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues)